# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(loadUrl_failed, Failed parsing the URL in flutter web view

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

On my flutter application, a Webview widget works normally on Android devices but is is not working on iOS devices.

it show me this error :

```dart
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(loadUrl_failed, Failed parsing the URL
```

**Notes**

the url am using have some kind of string that present a list, which I need to parse a list on my back end .

```dart
/en/map_page/false/[14,13,11]/37.33049888/-122.02873696/
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue. I solved it by:

```
WebView(
   initialUrl: Uri.parse(pageUrl).toString(),
   javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
   ),
```

Where pageUrl is the string value URL to be loaded